# Visual Studio 2019 Edits My C++ Code And Ruins My Iterator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tree, iterator, binary-tree

I have spent some time recently designing an iterator for the AVL Tree (right now it just has the inserting mechanics though; haven't implemented tree balancing).
I wanted to test out the iterator, so I checked how to make it online and settled on making it by having a stack holding the tree nodes (e.g. in normal iteration stack would contain all nodes left of `this->top` node).

This is how the iteration is supposed to work:

```
for (auto it = tree.iterator(); it.hasNext(); it.next())
{
    // process
}
```

However, VS changes (disables) my `Iterator(const Iterator& it)` and `Iterator(Iterator&& it)` constructors and then the iteration fails because the stack is always empty.
After setting `Iterator() = delete;`, I run into the issue of stack having an unusually large size with invisible parameters.

If extra information is needed, feel free to ask. I think that it's best if I just paste the relevant code because I do not understand this behaviour and do not know what details I should say:

```cpp
avlTree<Key, Info>::iterator:

class Iterator
    {
    private:
        std::vector<Node*> stack;
        bool reverse;
        Node* ptr;

        std::vector<Node*> makeStack(Node* start, long height)
        {
            std::vector<Node*> newStack;
            newStack.reserve(height);
            while (start != nullptr)
            {
                newStack.push_back(start);
                if (reverse)
                    start = start->right;
                else
                    start = start->left;
            }
            return newStack;
        }

        Iterator(Node* start, long height, bool reverse = false) : reverse(reverse), ptr(nullptr)
        {
            stack = makeStack(start, height);
        }

        friend class avlTree;
    public:
        Iterator(Iterator&& iterator)
        {
            stack = move(iterator.stack);
            ptr = nullptr;
        }
        Iterator(const Iterator& iterator)
        {
            stack = iterator.stack;
            ptr = nullptr;
        }
        //Iterator() = delete;

        bool hasNext()
        {
            return stack.size() > 0;
        }
        void next()
        {
            if (!stack.size()) throw "Empty iterator stack";
            if (ptr == stack[stack.size() - 1])
            {
                stack.pop_back();
                if (reverse)        // fill the stack with the subsequent nodes (reverse or normal direction)
                {
                    Node* start = ptr->left;
                    while (start != nullptr)
                    {
                        stack.push_back(start);
                        start = start->right;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Node* start = ptr->right;
                    while (start != nullptr)
                    {
                        stack.push_back(start);
                        start = start->left;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (stack.size() > 0)
                ptr = stack[stack.size() - 1];
        }
        const Key& getKey()
        {
            if (!ptr) throw "ptr is nullptr";
            else return ptr->key;
        }
        Info& getInfo()
        {
            if (!ptr) throw "ptr is nullptr";
            else return ptr->info;
        }
    };


main:

avlTree<char, int> tester;
for (char i = 'g'; i <= 'z'; ++i)
    tester.insert(i);
for (char i = 'a'; i < 'g'; ++i)
    tester.insert(i);

for (auto it = tester.iterator(); it.hasNext(); it.next())
{
    std::cout << it.getKey() << " ";
}
```

Screenshot of the code & message I get while debugging: http://prntscr.com/qi79zd

How do I fix the issue and make the iteration work?

EDIT:

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
//#include <ctime>

template<typename T>
void swap(T& a, T& b)
{
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

template<typename Key, typename Info>
class avlTree
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        const Key key;
        Info info;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
        long leftHeight, rightHeight;

        Node(const Key& key, Info&& info = Info(), Node* left = nullptr, Node* right = nullptr)
            : key(key), info(info), left(left), right(right), leftHeight(1), rightHeight(1) {}
        Node& operator()(Node* nleft, Node* nright)
        {
            left = nleft;
            right = nright;
            return *this;
        }
        Node& operator()(long left, long right)
        {
            leftHeight = left;
            rightHeight = right;
        }
    };

    Node* top;

    long length;

public:

    class Iterator
    {
    private:
        std::vector<Node*> stack;
        bool reverse;
        Node* ptr;

        std::vector<Node*> makeStack(Node* start, long height)
        {
            std::vector<Node*> newStack;
            newStack.reserve(height);
            while (start != nullptr)
            {
                newStack.push_back(start);
                if (reverse)
                    start = start->right;
                else
                    start = start->left;
            }
            return newStack;
        }

        Iterator(Node* start, long height, bool reverse = false) : reverse(reverse), ptr(nullptr)
        {
            stack = makeStack(start, height);
        }

        friend class avlTree;
    public:
        Iterator(Iterator&& iterator)
        {
            stack = move(iterator.stack);
            ptr = nullptr;
        }
        Iterator(const Iterator& iterator)
        {
            stack = iterator.stack;
            ptr = nullptr;
        }

        bool hasNext()
        {
            return stack.size() > 0;
        }
        void next()
        {
            if (!stack.size()) throw "Empty iterator stack";

            //stack.insert(stack.end(), vector.begin(), vector.end());
            if (ptr == stack[stack.size() - 1])
            {
                stack.pop_back();
                if (reverse)
                {
                    Node* start = ptr->left;
                    while (start != nullptr)
                    {
                        stack.push_back(start);
                        start = start->right;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Node* start = ptr->right;
                    while (start != nullptr)
                    {
                        stack.push_back(start);
                        start = start->left;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (stack.size() > 0)
                ptr = stack[stack.size() - 1];
        }
        const Key& getKey()
        {
            if (!ptr) throw "ptr is nullptr";
            else return ptr->key;
        }
        Info& getInfo()
        {
            if (!ptr) throw "ptr is nullptr";
            else return ptr->info;
        }
    };

    avlTree()
    {
        this->top = nullptr;
        this->length = 0;
    }

    ~avlTree()
    {
        recursiveDelete(top);
        length = 0;
    }
    void printAsc()
    {
        for (auto it = iterator(); it.hasNext(); it.next())
        {
            std::cout << it.getKey() << " " << it.getInfo() << "\n";
        }
    }
    void printDesc()
    {
        recDesc(top);
    }

    void printTop()
    {
        if (top)    // != nullptr
        {
            std::cout << ".." << top->key << std::endl;
            if (top->left)
                std::cout << "." << top->left->key << "..";
            else std::cout << ".0..";
            if (top->right)
                std::cout << top->right->key << std::endl;
            else std::cout << "0" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void insert(const Key& key);
    long height()
    {
        return !top ? 0 : top->leftHeight > top->rightHeight ? top->leftHeight : top->rightHeight;
    }

private:
    void recDesc(Node* parent);
    void recursiveDelete(Node* parent);
    void insertRecursive(Node* parent, const Key& key, int& depth);

//  void rightRotation(Node* top, Node* parent = nullptr);
public:

    Iterator iterator()
    {
        return Iterator(top, height());
    }

};

std::vector<std::string> readFile(bool toDarwin = true);

/****************************************************************************/

int main()
{
    // auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    avlTree<std::string, int> counter;

    avlTree<char, int> tester;
    for (char i = 'g'; i <= 'z'; ++i)
        tester.insert(i);
    for (char i = 'a'; i < 'g'; ++i)
        tester.insert(i);

    for (auto it = tester.iterator(); it.hasNext(); it.next())
    {
        std::cout << it.getKey() << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}

/****************************************************************************/

template<typename Key, typename Info>
void avlTree<Key, Info>::recDesc(Node* parent)
{
    if (parent->left != nullptr)
        recAsc(parent->left);

    std::cout << parent->key;

    if (parent->right != nullptr)
        recAsc(parent->left);
}

template<typename Key, typename Info>
void avlTree<Key, Info>::recursiveDelete(Node* parent)
{
    if (!parent) return;
    if (parent->left != nullptr)
        recursiveDelete(parent->left);
    if (parent->right != nullptr)
        recursiveDelete(parent->right);
    delete parent;
}

template<typename Key, typename Info>
void avlTree<Key, Info>::insertRecursive(Node* parent, const Key& key, int& depth)
{
    if (parent->key == key)
        ++(parent->info);
    else if (parent->key > key)
    {
        if (parent->left == nullptr)
        {
            parent->left = new Node(key);
            ++(parent->left->info);
            ++length;
            depth = 1;
            // (* parent->left)(depth, depth)
        }
        else
        {
            insertRecursive(parent->left, key, depth);
            ++depth;
            parent->leftHeight = depth;
        }
    }
    else if (parent->key < key)
    {
        if (parent->right == nullptr)
        {
            parent->right = new Node(key);
            ++(parent->right->info);
            ++length;
            depth = 1;
            // (* parent->right)(depth, depth)
        }
        else
        {
            insertRecursive(parent->right, key, depth);
            ++depth;
            parent->rightHeight = depth;
        }
    }
}

template<typename Key, typename Info>
void avlTree<Key, Info>::insert(const Key& key)
{
    int depth = 0;
    if (!top)
    {
        top = new Node(key);
        // (*top)(1, 1)
        ++length;
        ++(top->info);
    }
    else
    {
        insertRecursive(top, key, depth);
        ++depth;
        top->key > key ? ++(top->leftHeight) : top->key < key ? ++(top->rightHeight) : NULL;
    }
}

/* Irrelevant to the problem
std::vector<std::string> readFile(bool toDarwin)
{
    // shrink_to_fit()
    std::ifstream file;
    std::string word;

    std::vector<std::string> words;
    words.reserve(1000000);

    if (toDarwin == 1)
        file.open("OnTheOriginOfSpecies.txt");
    else
        file.open("The_bible.txt");

    while (file >> word)
    {
        words.push_back(word);
    }
    words.shrink_to_fit();
    return words;
}
*/
```

Comment: You should post code that will compile and build without having us to add or remove lines from the code you posted.

Comment: VS is just saying that because it either optimized it all away or it inlined it all. Are you compiling in release or debut? Also what is `tester.iterator()`

Comment: Paul, I have added it now.

Comment: The message is pretty clear. You set a breakpoint on a line of code that is not associated with any code in the compiled program, because of the reasons listed in the message. Your original (uncompiled) code remains unchanged and the behaviour of your program also did not change. Either the debugger has some hickups (clean & rebuild might help), or the code was for some reason optimized away. (for debugging, compile in debug mode)

Comment: I am running it in Debug. `tester.iterator()` returns `Iterator(top, height())`, `height()` being the tree height.
I have tried changing the Debug mode to Mixed, but the result is the same.

Comment: @Croder Thanks for supplying the code.  Your `Iterator` violates the rule of 3 by not supplying an assignment operator.  Even so, your copy constructor is highly flawed (and to be honest, bogus), since it fails to make an actual copy of the object in terms of all of the members (you only handle `stack`, and `ptr` while `reverse` is not copied (and thus is uninitialized)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are not aware of RVO - return value optimization. Most compilers do so and in fact it is mandatory in C++17. What's RVO?

```
class A;

A func()
{
     A a_infunc = {};
     return a_infunc;
}

//use
A a_outsidefunc = func();
```

In this simple example at no point `A::A(const A&)` or `A::A(A&&)` is called. `a_infunc` is exactly the same variable as `a_outsidefunc`.

So in the for-loop:

```
for (auto it = tree.iterator(); it.hasNext(); it.next())
{
    // process
}
```

There will be no calls to `Iterator(const Iterator& it)` or `Iterator(Iterator&& it)` due to RVO.

Comment: I understand, thank you. That means that I have to find a mistake elsewhere in the code.

Comment: I've found the mistake.
I had to initialise `ptr` to `stack[stack.size() - 1]` after creating the stack instead of `nullptr` in the private constructor.